# Tags and Templates with Plugin Conflict

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, tags

I am using WP Courseware (www.flyplugins.com) for a client's site and my basic understanding is that the course units are basically a custom post type ('course_units'). The course units can be created directly or converted from posts.

WP Courseware does not support category or tags taxonomy out of the box and it had to be enabled.

All of that was said to say that when I have posts tagged that they show up when you call http://domain.com/tag/design/ however the course units tagged with "design" do not show up.  I have never bothered with tags enough to care about tag clouds, etc so I do not know what file, template or function that needs to be updated to support the custom post type of "course_units" when it displays posts containing tags.

I followed the advice found here: [Combining tags from post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137617/combining-tags-from-post-types)

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'portfolio' );
```

And now I see Tags under my Course Units in WP Dashboard.  I click on Tags and see the tags and click on the count and it shows the course units that tagged correctly in the backend, so I just need to know how to enable support on Tag Cloud for the front end where it actually returns the course unit posts instead of "Sorry, no content matched your criteria."

What connection am I missing?

Comment: I am not looking to add query variables to the URL.  I need to know why, when the tags are associated with the custom posts in the backend, that there is no association with the tag cloud on the front end.

Comment: I reviewed the solution in the referenced post and it doesn't change the output. `function post_type_tags_fix($request) {
    if ( isset($request['tag']) && !isset($request['post_type']) )
    $request['post_type'] = 'course_unit';
    return $request;
} 
add_filter('request', 'post_type_tags_fix');`  I still get no results found

Comment: Query vars are always present, regardless of whether or not they're immediately visible in a URL - you can safely ignore that part of the linked question. The problem is that the front-end's default behavior for tag archives is to query only the `'post'` post type. You need it to query either `'any'` or `['post','course_unit']`.

Comment: Just to be clear - what is the course post type? In your description you list it as `'course_units'`, however you reference it in the comments as `'course_unit'` - that one 's' can make a world of difference ;)

Comment: I see what you mean.  I changed permalinks back to default and I see the ?tag= variable is set from the Tag Cloud.  I reviewed the answer code that I posted in my previous comment.  It still returns "Sorry, no content matched your criteria."  If I manually append ?post_type=course_unit I do get the desired results, but shouldn't the code snippet in the answer automatically assign course_unit?  That should work but it isn't.

Comment: The post type is "course_unit".

Comment: Manually adding the ?post_type=course_unit to the url gives the expected result.  The function isn't setting the request variable before the results rendered?

Comment: Seems that way... a few thoughts come to mind. Removing the second condition `&& !isset($request['post_type'])` should force all `tag` term queries to additionally display `course_unit`s, but may have adverse side-effects... I'll play with this in an hour or so and see if I can't give you a more complete answer!

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate your willingness to help me solve the mystery.

Comment: you can also do that via the `pre_get_posts` action like in [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47082/adding-categories-across-posts-and-custom-post-types). change `is_category()` to `is_tag()`.

Comment: @Milo's on point - a `pre_get_posts` action hook is also somewhat safer than a `request` filter.

Comment: I've tried that as well with no success.  I even tried Ultimate Tag Cloud Widget which allows you to select all Post Types for the cloud.  Still no success.  So the thought occurred to me that snce the Plugin authors did not originally intend for the course_unit post type to utilize Taxonomy that maybe they left out key features when they registered the course_unit post type.  I have pasted that function in the following pastein: http://pastebin.com/f9HMdPyD  Does anyone see any missing arguments that would prevent the course unit post type from showing up with any/all of the above changes?

Comment: Just one question, did you flush your permalinks again after make the changes. This is important

Comment: I did not.  IS there a particular hook that this should be executed in or priority? Thanks

Comment: Okay I tried the following: `/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'init', 'bt_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/* Flush your rewrite rules */
function bt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}` and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Well folks, foolish once again.  I was working with a new theme and adding the code to the child theme functions.php file when I was displaying the parent theme.  Boscho's solution does work. Thank you again

Comment: Awesome, Requin - glad it all worked out ;)